# Displaying a Toast message before UI Thread gets to sleep

Tags: android, multithreading

In my app I'm using a Thread.sleep so there's enough time to perform some actions that happen outside of the activity, those are actions about enabling and disabling some launchers for the app if the user has selected some option, but as I don't want the user to think that the app has been blocked I want to inform him to wait a little until new message.

Problem is that due to the asynchronicity of Android setting the toast message before the Thread.sleep call doesn't work, so it looks like the app has been blocked.

I've also used this code:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() 
    {
                    // a potentially  time consuming task
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"mymessage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
            }).start();

    [some more code]

    Thread.sleep(10000);
```

That i think should execute even if Thread.sleep is happening, but I get that the application crashes, but it's a rare crash, as it shows the message on my android device but everything looks normal in debug mode, to the point that I can keep on debugging the app.

Any idea on how to achieve that Toast, that shows the message, even while Thread.sleep is executing?

Comment: Never call `Thread.sleep()` in the UI thread.  And don't call `Toast` in a non-UI thread.  You should read up on `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I'll check, thanks.

Comment: The toast will never show, because for any UI updates to occur the UI needs to be drawn.  That only happens if control returns to the message queue in the framework, which won't happen as long as you're sleeping.  Never sleep on the UI thread due to this.